# Stacked 2D plots with interconnections in Matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, scatter-plot, mplot3d

I need to visualize some complex multivariate datasets and the preferrable choice is to use a modification of parallel axis visualization, using stacked 2D plots, where each plot maps a degree of freedom/model parameter and data points belonging to the same data sets should be interconnected across different plots. I am attaching a conceptual sketch. How could I implement it in `matplotlib`?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To have a rough idea, this could be a possible solution in matplotlib using `Axes3D`

```
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.patches import Rectangle, PathPatch
import mpl_toolkits.mplot3d.art3d as art3d


x = np.array([1,2,3])
y = np.array([2,3,1])
z = np.array([1,1,1])


fig = plt.figure(figsize=(6,6))
ax = fig.add_axes([0,0,1,1], projection='3d')

#plot the points
ax.scatter(x,y,z*0.4, c="r", facecolor="r", s=60)
ax.scatter(y,x,z*0.9, c="b", facecolor="b", s=60)
ax.scatter(x,y,z*1.6, c="g", facecolor="g", s=60)
#plot connection lines
ax.plot([x[0],y[0],x[0]],[y[0],x[0],y[0]],[0.4,0.9,1.6], color="k")
ax.plot([x[2],y[2],x[2]],[y[2],x[2],y[2]],[0.4,0.9,1.6], color="k")
#plot planes
p = Rectangle((0,0), 4,4, color="r", alpha=0.2)
ax.add_patch(p)
art3d.pathpatch_2d_to_3d(p, z=0.4, zdir="z")

p = Rectangle((0,0), 4,4, color="b", alpha=0.2)
ax.add_patch(p)
art3d.pathpatch_2d_to_3d(p, z=0.9, zdir="z")

p = Rectangle((0,0), 4,4, color="g", alpha=0.2)
ax.add_patch(p)
art3d.pathpatch_2d_to_3d(p, z=1.6, zdir="z")



ax.set_aspect('equal')
ax.view_init(13,-63)
ax.set_xlim3d([0,4])
ax.set_ylim3d([0,4])
ax.set_zlim3d([0,2])

plt.savefig(__file__+".png")
plt.show()
```

[image]

---

**Update**

Creating three different axes is possible. One has to add the axes and make the upper ones transparent (`ax2.patch.set_alpha(0.)`). Then the grid has to be turned off (`ax.grid(False)`) and the panes and lines that we don't need set invisible.
However, I have no clue how to draw a connection with between the axes. The 2D approach of `matplotlib.patches.ConnectionPatch` does not work for 3D axes.

```
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.patches import Rectangle
import mpl_toolkits.mplot3d.art3d as art3d


x = np.array([1,2,3])
y = np.array([2,3,1])
z = np.array([0,0,0])


fig = plt.figure(figsize=(6,6))

ax = fig.add_axes([0,0,1,1], projection='3d')
ax2 = fig.add_axes([0.0,0.24,1,1], projection='3d')
ax2.patch.set_alpha(0.)
ax3 = fig.add_axes([0.0,0.48,1,1], projection='3d')
ax3.patch.set_alpha(0.)
#plot the points
ax.scatter(x,y,z, c="r", facecolor="r", s=60)
ax2.scatter(y*4,x*4,z, c="b", facecolor="b", s=60)
ax3.scatter(x*100,y*100,z, c="g", facecolor="g", s=60)
#plot connection lines
#ax.plot([x[0],y[0],x[0]],[y[0],x[0],y[0]],[0.4,0.9,1.6], color="k")
#ax.plot([x[2],y[2],x[2]],[y[2],x[2],y[2]],[0.4,0.9,1.6], color="k")

#plot planes
p = Rectangle((0,0), 4,4, color="r", alpha=0.2)
ax.add_patch(p)
art3d.pathpatch_2d_to_3d(p, z=0, zdir="z")

p = Rectangle((0,0), 16,16, color="b", alpha=0.2)
ax2.add_patch(p)
art3d.pathpatch_2d_to_3d(p, z=0, zdir="z")

p = Rectangle((0,0), 400,400, color="g", alpha=0.2)
ax3.add_patch(p)
art3d.pathpatch_2d_to_3d(p, z=0, zdir="z")



ax.set_aspect('equal')
ax2.set_aspect('equal')
ax3.set_aspect('equal')
ax.view_init(13,-63)
ax2.view_init(10,-63)
ax3.view_init(8,-63)
ax.set_xlim3d([0,4])
ax.set_ylim3d([0,4])
ax.set_zlim3d([0,2])
ax2.set_xlim3d([0,16])
ax2.set_ylim3d([0,16])
ax2.set_zlim3d([0,2])
ax3.set_xlim3d([0,400])
ax3.set_ylim3d([0,400])
ax3.set_zlim3d([0,2])
ax.grid(False)
ax2.grid(False)
ax3.grid(False)

def axinvisible(ax):
    for zax in (ax.w_zaxis, ax.w_xaxis, ax.w_yaxis):
        zax.pane.set_visible(False)
        if zax == ax.w_zaxis:
            zax.line.set_visible(False)
            for ll in zax.get_ticklines()+zax.get_ticklabels():
                    ll.set_visible(False)


axinvisible(ax)
axinvisible(ax2)
axinvisible(ax3)

# setting a ConnectionPatch does NOT work
from matplotlib.patches import ConnectionPatch
con = ConnectionPatch(xyA=(2,2), xyB=(2,2), 
                      coordsA='data', coordsB='data', 
                      axesA=ax, axesB=ax2,
                      arrowstyle='->', clip_on=True)
ax2.add_artist(con) # artist is not shown :-(

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. However, the rectangles that I specified above are supposed to be different data planes / axis. Meaning, they represent different parameters and thus represent points in different spaces. So I believe there are two problems at least: (i) to draw axes in a stacked fashion (should be relatively easy); (ii) to interconnect points across different axes (this will be hard, because the only way is to have a metrics that includes all points...)

Comment: I have not solved yet the issue of stacked plots, which should be relatively straight forward, but for connections between plots, `matplotlib.patches.ConnectionPatch` should do the trick, although the doc does not say whether this method works on `Axes3D` objects...

Comment: I have solved the issue of stacked plots (see update). But I have no idea how to connect them.

Comment: Thanks this is aiming in the direction that I wanted! Regretfully I see that `ConnectionPatch` does no work... Let me see if anyone else is going to comment and/or some folks from `matplotlib` want to throw their ideas, before approving your answer.

Comment: This might actually be not implemented. If I replace `ax.add_patch` to your last `ax2.add_artist` instance, I get the following: `AttributeError: 'ConnectionPatch' object has no attribute 'do_3d_projection'`.

Comment: Actually I have a further question on this topic, since `projection='3d'` is not documented at the moment as an acceptable keyword (see http://matplotlib.org/api/figure_api.html). What's the default `projection`? `'rectilinear'` I assume, isn't it?

Comment: I don't see how this question relates to the topic. In principle you are right, in the source code you'll find somewhere `if projection is None:
        projection = 'rectilinear'`, but if you want to know more, I'd suggest to ask a new question about it, which I can answer in more detail.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest very nice answer! Is it possible to stack the axes horizontally instead of vertically? I mean to have horizontal x axes and vertical y axes at 3 different positions?

Comment: @Pincopallino It's sure possible to do the same thing stacking the planes horizontally. In the first solution this should be straight forward, just using vertical planes. In the second solution, you would need to find good parameters for the axes' positions. I would encourage you to choose one of the two options, try to implement it and if there is a problem, ask a new question with a clear problem description about it.

Answer (score 0):

A solution could be based on [matplotlib's 3D capabilities](http://matplotlib.org/mpl_toolkits/mplot3d/tutorial.html). You can use `Axes3D.plot_surface` to plot the axes, and user scatter and line plots for the rest.